Why webdriver causes memory leak in java spring boot application when using multiple threads even after driverThreadLocal.remove()?
Webdriver is causing a memory leak in my spring boot application. Even after the driver quits, the memory is not fully released causing a memory leak.
I'm running 2 separate threads and each thread follow some steps each time they are requested:

Starts the driver;
Navigates to a webpage, in this example it is google.com;
Close the driver;

Here is the code I wrote:
Main class:
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
public class App {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);    
        
        //REQUESTING THE ENDPOINT THROUGH CODE
        RestTemplate restTemplate = context.getBean(RestTemplate.class);
        restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/hello", Void.class);
    }
}

Config class:
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig {
    
    @Bean(name="asyncTaskExecutor")
    public Executor asyncTaskExecutor(){
        System.out.println("CONFIGURING ASYNC TASKS");
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor(); 
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2); 
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2); 
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100); 
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async Thread-"); 
        executor.initialize();
        return executor; 
    }
    
    
    // Configuração do RestTemplate
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
}

Service class:
@Service
public class MyService{
    
    
    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driverThreadLocal = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> null);
    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driverThreadLocal.get();
    }
    
    public static void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        driverThreadLocal.set(driver);
    }
    
    public static void quitDriver() {
        getDriver().quit();
        driverThreadLocal.remove();
    }   
    
    @Async("asyncTaskExecutor")
        public void scrappingtask() throws IOException {
            System.out.println("REQUEST STARTS");
            System.out.println("Thread group: "+Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup());
            System.out.println("Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        
        
        if (getDriver() == null) {
            System.out.println("*******WEBDRIVER START FOR THE THREAD "+ Thread.currentThread().getName()); 
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","YOUR_CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PATH"); 
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            options.addArguments("--disable-cache");
            driverThreadLocal.set(new ChromeDriver(options));
        } 
        
        System.out.println("WEBDRIVER'S SESSION_ID FOR THE THREAD "+ Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+((ChromeDriver)driverThreadLocal.get()).getSessionId());

        getDriver().get("https://google.com");
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        System.out.println("REQUEST ENDS");
        quitDriver(); 
    }
}

Test cases:
@Controller
public class TestCases {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myservice;
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
        public synchronized void runtestcases() throws IOException {
            int i;
            for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                myservice.scrappingtask();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block          
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }
}

I was expecting to have a heap memory always at the same level of beggining of the process, but it keeps increasing as we can see on the images below:
VisualVM monitor screen
Heap Dump

When running the code previously there was no limit to the HEAP MEMORY SIZE, so the system was not performing optimizations for memory.
New Poolchunks were getting allocated and as the memory was sufficient to extend the HEAP SIZE, the system did not get forced to clean them.
More information about the poolchunk process is available here.
After deleting the line executor.setMaxPoolSize(2); from my configuration and setting a maximum heap memory on the run configurations of eclipse the problem get solved.

As we can see the heap data use decreased when running the same code after these changes:

And from a thread dump, we can notice the poolchunks are no longer getting cumulated.
